# Twitter third party app not retrieving email

Tags: email, twitter, passport.js, loopbackjs

I'm using loopback and passport to login to an app via twitter. The problem is that when I log in, the email I get from my twitter profile data is something like this:

```
username@loopback.twitter.com
```

which obviously, its not my actual email address.

I there something with twitter apps that hide email addresses? I couldn't find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you link your accounts, i think it will be solved.

Actually it causes from this [code line](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-component-passport/blob/master/lib/models/user-identity.js#L50)

```
var email = profile.emails && profile.emails[0] && profile.emails[0].value;
if (!email) {
  // Fake an e-mail
  email = (profile.username || profile.id) + '@loopback.' +
          (profile.provider || provider) + '.com';
}
```

You can get more info from [Login and account linking](http://docs.strongloop.com/pages/releaseview.action?pageId=3836277)